# MySql How to count results that have been already fetched with SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Html table is populated with data retrieved from database using SELECT query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `doc_title`, `date`, `status` FROM `table_name` WHERE `user_id` = 25");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $row['doc_title'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['date'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['status'] .'</td>
         </tr>';
}
```

Is there a way to count how many of retrieved records have $row['status'] == 1, and how many have $row['status'] == 2 without running a separate SELECT COUNT query?

Comment: If `user_id` is indexed, another query is very, very cheap, so don't alter your presentation layer too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user_id` is indexed, another query is very, very cheap, so don't alter your presentation layer too much.

But if you must, I'd do this:

```
$statuses = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  @$statuses[ $row['status'] ]++;
}

var_dump($statuses[1], $statuses[2]);
```

The `@` is for the first status added to `$statuses` that doesn't exist yet. You might want to use `isset()` instead. Some people are very anti-`@`:

```
$statuses = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  isset($statuses[ $row['status'] ]) or $statuses[ $row['status'] ] = 0;
  $statuses[ $row['status'] ]++;
}
```

but I think it's actually less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Inside while you could have 2 variables to count:

```
$status1 = 0;
$status2 = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($row['status'] == 1) 
        $status1++;
    else if($row['status'] == 2)
        $status2++;

    echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $row['doc_title'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['date'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['status'] .'</td>
         </tr>';
}
```

Also, you can use a switch statement in a similar manner.